# Unusual number triads

Tags: mathematics

Let's have the following equations.

$1388^2+803^2=137^3$

$236^2+115^2=41^3$

$666^2+413^2=85^3$

As you can verify by visual inspection the numbers of each triad have (GCD)=1.

Question 1) How can we obtain more such triads?

Question 2) What is the required method to find such triads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No previous answers addressed the GCD=1 part, so here it is.

First of all, note that

> the base number $n$ in $a^2 + b^2 = n$ must allow a pair $(a,b)$ such that $GCD(a,b)=1$.

Then use happystar's method to get the general formula for $A^2 + B^2 = C^3$:

> $$\begin{align}&(a^2+b^2)^3 \\=&(a+bi)^3 (a-bi)^3 \\=&(a^3 + 3a^2bi - 3ab^2 - b^3i)(a^3 - 3a^2bi - 3ab^2 + b^3i) \\=&((a^3 - 3ab^2) + (3a^2b - b^3)i)((a^3 - 3ab^2) - (3a^2b - b^3)i) \\=&(a^3 - 3ab^2)^2 + (3a^2b - b^3)^2\end{align}$$

So we get

> $A = a^3 - 3ab^2, B = 3a^2b - b^3, C = a^2+b^2 = n$.

Then the requirement is

> $$GCD(A,B,C) = GCD(a^3-3ab^2, 3a^2b-b^3, a^2+b^2) = 1$$

The LHS simplifies into

> $$ \begin{align}&GCD\left(a^2+b^2, a(a^2-3b^2), b(3a^2-b^2)\right) \\=&GCD\left(GCD\left(a^2+b^2, a(a^2-3b^2)\right), GCD\left(a^2+b^2, b(3a^2-b^2)\right)\right) \\=&GCD\left(GCD(a^2+b^2, a^2-3b^2), GCD(a^2+b^2, 3a^2-b^2)\right) \\=&GCD\left(GCD(a^2+b^2, 4b^2), GCD(a^2+b^2, 4a^2)\right) \\=&GCD(a^2+b^2, 4a^2, 4b^2) \\=&GCD\left(a^2+b^2, GCD(4a^2, 4b^2)\right) \\=&GCD(a^2+b^2, 4) \\=&GCD(n, 4)\end{align}$$

Therefore,

> if $n$ is odd and admits a coprime two-squares decomposition, it will always lead to a coprime construction of $A^2+B^2=C^3$. According to *Introduction to the theory of numbers* by Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery ([huge pdf](https://undergraduatemaths.files.wordpress.com/2017/12/ivan_niven_herbert_s-_zuckerman_hugh_l-_montgoman-introduction-to-the-theory-of-numbers.pdf), page 164, Theorem 3.20), the condition (odd $n$ with coprime two-squares decomposition) is equivalent to **being the product of primes of the form** $4k+1$.

Answer (score 7):

The following method works for $41^3$

> $ 41^3 = (25+16)^3 = (5+4i)^3(5-4i)^3 = (-115 + 236i)(-115 + 236i) = 115^2 + 236^2$

The same method works for $N^3$ provided

> $N$ is the sum of two squares, and it is well known this is always possible if $N$ is a prime of form $4k+1$ (or a product of such primes).

Comment: "and it is well known this is always possible if N has a prime factor of form 4k+1." ??? Like $N=15$, say? Rest is good, though (+1).

Comment: Oops, N must be a product of primes of form 4k+1

Comment: With a single method also we can obtain solutions of the form $495^2+4888^2=289^3$ and $23^3+(77 √2)^2=155^2$.

Comment: As you've written most of it out anyways, you might as well note that a number is a sum of two squares if (and only if) it can be written as a square number times a product of primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt That can't be right either: Counter examples: 1+1, 1+9, 9+25, ...

Comment: @PaulPanzer Oops, I forgot about $2$ - "a square number times a product of primes not of the form $4k+3$" would be the right statement.